# how to set data from sql query into the gridview template field

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my SQL query I retrieve 3 strings and the 3rd string has an URL. I created 2 templatefield contain labels and another template with an image. Now I want to set the values to the two labels and view the image by setting ImageUrl and display all the rows coming out from SQL query.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //if (IsPostBack == false)
    //{
    //    grdMaterial.DataBind();
    //}
    try
    {
        matType = int.Parse(Session["mattype"].ToString());
        colorId = int.Parse(Session["color"].ToString());
        matStyleId = int.Parse(Session["matstyle"].ToString());
        try
        {
            matContent = Session["matContent"].ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            panAval.Visible = true;
            panNew.Visible = false;
            dtab = new DBHELPER().getdataTable("SELECT [item_Id],[mat_Content],[mat_Image] FROM [item] WHERE [mat_Content]='" + matContent + "'");
            //grdMaterial.DataSource = dtab;
            //grdMaterial.DataBind();



    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
    }

}

protected void grdMaterial_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dtab.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            //TextBox x = (TextBox)GridViewCarrinho.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("txtQuantidade");


            Label itemId = (Label)grdMaterial.FindControl("lblItemId");
            itemId.Text = dtab.Rows[i]["item_Id"].ToString();

            Label matContent = (Label)grdMaterial.FindControl("lblItemName");
            matContent.Text = dtab.Rows[i]["mat_Content"].ToString();

            Image itemImage = (Image)grdMaterial.FindControl("imgItemImage");
            itemImage.ImageUrl = dtab.Rows[i]["mat_Image"].ToString();

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. You have posted the actual question in the title. The title is used to describe the problem in few words. See how others ask questions.

Answer (score 2):

This event: grdMaterial_Load  does not seem necessary.

You can simply bind your datasource to your datagrid and simply customize the datagrid to get the image, and populate the labels.

Simply bind your ItemID and ItemName columns, then create a template field for the image as shown below...

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdMaterial" runat="server" DataKeyNames="item_Id" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="item_Id" HeaderText="Item Id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mat_Content" HeaderText="Item Name"  />
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="imgItemImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "mat_Image")) %>" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```